How to have a dialog with tooltip where the tooltip does not reopen when the Dialog is closed using shadcn ui / Radix ui
I am currently using the code below for the tooltip dialog combo
<Dialog
      open={isModalOpen}
      onOpenChange={async (open) => {
        setIsModalOpen(open);
        closeTooltip();
      }}
    >
      <TooltipProvider>
        <Tooltip>
          <DialogTrigger asChild>
            <TooltipTrigger asChild>
              <Button
                variant="ghost"
                id="browse-prompt"
                ref={triggerRef}
                className="grid aspect-square h-9 w-9 place-items-center rounded-full p-0 hover:bg-accent"
              >
                <Chrome className="h-5 w-5 text-white" />
                <span className="sr-only">Browse Prompts</span>
              </Button>
            </TooltipTrigger>
          </DialogTrigger>
          <TooltipContent>
            <h3 className="text-base font-semibold">Browse Prompt</h3>
            <p>Find useful prompts from others</p>
            <Arrow color="white" fill="white"></Arrow>
          </TooltipContent>
           // Dialog Content
        
             </Tooltip>
      </TooltipProvider>
    </Dialog>


But when ever I close the dialog the tooltip reopens , I don't want that behavior.
I tried to use my own seperate state for the tooltip , and set the tooltip closed when ever my dialog was open but ,
 onOpenChange={async (open) => {
        setIsModalOpen(open);
        if(!open) setIsTooltipOpen(false)
      }}

it did not work as I set the onOpenChange of the tooltip to setIsTooltipOpen as well in this case. It seems like the tooltip is opened after some time after the dialog is closed
I also tired to dispach a mouseout event in the button but that also did not work.
I tried clicking on the document after I closed the dialog and even that did not work
How can i fix it ?
I am expecting the tooltip to not reopen when I close the dialog. I should go away unless I rehover in the trigger again.

use this in the dialog component: onDismiss={() => {setIsModalOpen(false); closeTooltip()}}

To make this work, you should not use nested triggers. It is also enough to keep the open state only for the dialog. Reorganize the code as follows to make it work.
<TooltipProvider>
  <Tooltip>
    <TooltipTrigger asChild>
      <Button
        variant="ghost"
        id="browse-prompt"
        onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}
        className="grid aspect-square h-9 w-9 place-items-center rounded-full p-0 hover:bg-accent"
      >
        <Chrome className="h-5 w-5 text-white" />
        <span className="sr-only">Browse Prompts</span>
      </Button>
    </TooltipTrigger>
    <TooltipContent>
      <h3 className="text-base font-semibold">Browse Prompt</h3>
      <p>Find useful prompts from others</p>
      <Arrow color="white" fill="white"></Arrow>
    </TooltipContent>
  </Tooltip>

  <Dialog open={isModalOpen} onOpenChange={setIsModalOpen}>
    // Dialog Content
    // call your action handler here by adding simple onClick={handleButtonClick} directly to dialog buttons
  </Dialog>
</TooltipProvider>

